# WordPress not showing manually uploaded files in Uploads folder on Media Library

Tags: plugins, uploads, media-library

I'm having a script on my wordpress site that uploads file to my site directory at wp-content/uploads while .mp3 is the file extension uploaded by that script.
This script worked successfully but when I login to wordpress to visit the media library I couldn't find the files right there.
Please is there a permanent way to fix this?

Comment: WordPress only knows about files that are recorded in the database. If you're bypassing that whole upload system and placing files straight into the directory, they don't exist as far as WP is concerned.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.